# How do I get rid of the Adobe Download Manager

Tags: download, download-manager

Somehow I have got the Adobe Download Manager installed on my PC, and it opens up periodically. I don't know what triggers it.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was opening when I opened Firefox. Adobe seems to have silently installed an add-in for it :-(  Bad Adobe! Bad! No doughnut! Bad!

Deleting the add-in seems to have gotten rid of that annoying window.

Answer (score 2):

It should appear in Add/Remove Programs (or "Programs and Features", depending on your version of Windows). Select it and uninstall.

Note that you'll probably have to use it again if you're updating or installing Flash or Reader.

Comment: No, for some odd reason it doesn't go away completely when you uninstall from Add/Remove programs. and keeps giving you errors if you do so

Comment: There's a trick how to avoid its installation. When downloading plug-in for Firefox, use Internet Explorer. Then run the stand-a;one installer. Same thing for IE plug-in. Download it with Firefox and run it later. This way ADM is not used.

Answer (score 0):

> Try Uninstalling it with **Revo
>   Uninstaller**, it worked for other
>   people